# Lynx incremental search

Tags: grep, find, search, lynx

I am trying to run an incremental search using `lynx`.

Imagine a page, for example, an `index_of` page which contains several folders which also contain other subfolders and files. I want to run `lynx` in a way that I can enter automatically in each folder/page and search for a string, so it returns me the link which contains the string found.

For example, if I am looking for a specific datasheet in http://datasheets.chipdb.org/ so I would try something like

`find . -name "mydatasheet.pdf" |lynx -dump http://datasheets.chipdb.org`

but that I could run in all subfolders recursively. Maybe some `grep` or whatever.

How could it be done?

Comment: Isn't lynx a text based browser? How can it do an incremental search?

Comment: Well, that's exactly the question. But you can identify the links based on a link pattern.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe I don't understand your question but if I were trying to find a link to a pdf file I would write a python script.  Something like:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import urllib2
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
def find_links ( url ):
        try:
                soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib2.urlopen( url ).read())
        except:
                return
        links = soup.findAll( "a" )
        for link in links:
                pdfurl = link.get('href')
                m = re.search( "^\?", pdfurl)
                if m:
                        continue
                m = re.search( ".pdf$", pdfurl)
                if m:
                        print "Found a pdf in %s/%s" % (url, pdfurl)
                else:
                        find_links( "%s/%s" % ( url, pdfurl) )

find_links( "http://datasheets.chipdb.org" )
```

Or a Perl script that uses `WWW::Mechanize`.